# Reflector Klystron and Isolator for ESR/EPR Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin, electrons, resonance

I am doing a lab on ESR/EPR, and I would like to know how the reflector klystron operates. It is very old and the company who made our model does not exist anymore and there are no operation manuals.

I would like to know how the electrons get "bunched together" (like the original klystrons) and produce coherent and collimated microwave radiation. My understanding is that the electrons produce radiation (from being accelerated) at some frequency and that gets fed back in like an op amp to produce more coherent radiation. If this is true how does, the produced microwaves cause the "bunching".

My lab instructor gave me an explanation that I was unable to follow. I am pretty confused about the operation and would very much appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: This [Pdf](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-10620.pdf) might be useful. Wiki quotes:"_In the moving frame of the electron beam, the velocity modulation is equivalent to a plasma oscillation._" Its a part of my curriculum ,just started studying it. I guess plasma oscillations and the cavity are the key concepts.

Comment: Google for *reflex* or *repeller klystron*. See for example http://www.radartutorial.eu/08.transmitters/Klystron.en.html and http://www.tpub.com/neets/book11/45d.htm